# jquery selector doesn't recognize link_to + anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a navbar on which I use a jquery function that generates a smooth scroll when someone click on a specific link.

My js code is that one :

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href*=\\#]', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
    }, 800);
});
```

And it works well when element in my navbar are written like this:

```
<div class="nav-element">
  <a href="#features">
    <%= t('landing.navbar.features') %>
  </a>
</div>
```

However, when I use the rails helper "link_to", written like this :

```
<div class="nav-element">
  <%= link_to root_path(anchor: "discover") do%>
    <%= t('landing.navbar.discover') %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The selector doesn't recognize my anchor because the locale is passed before the #.

The error I get in the console when I click on "discover" is that one :

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /fr#discover

How is it possible that even if I use `href*=\\#` , it doesn't detect the anchor in `/fr#` or `/en#` ? What could I do in order too keep using my `link_to` and still have my smooth scroll ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the `href` to get the hash value only:

```
// Hook on to all the links containing #
$(document).on('click', 'a[href*="#"]', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get the hash of the href only
    var hash = $(this).attr('href');
    hash = hash.substr(hash.lastIndexOf('#'));

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
    }, 800);
});
```

Comment: Hi muecas, thanks for your answer. It is finally working ! My only problem now is that when I am on another page, the js code prevent the link from opening. 
When I click on "discover" , I have this error in the console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined"` and the link doesn't open. How could I tweak this :) ? Thanks !

Comment: @adrappa the problem is that this will prevent any link with a `#` to open. The best solution will be to identify which links do you want to use for the smoothscroll. Maybe the best solution is to add a class to those links (could be `.smoothscroll`) so you could hook the click event only to those links: `$(document).on('click', 'a.smoothscroll', ...)`.

Comment: I wanted to avoid this solution but it seems like it'll be the only one working. Thanks again :)

Comment: @adrappa Yes, you have no other option than identfy the links in some way. :-(